# Moving the page file to a different folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, virtual-memory, pagefile

My Windows 8.1 To Go machine is always popping up saying it's low on memory, so I finally decided to make a page file. The problem is, I was going to make it on my largest hard drive on the computer. That hard drive has Windows 10 on it though, and the Windows 10 automatically created a page file on the hard drive. I didn't know that it did that, and when I tried to make the page file, it told me that pagefile.sys already existed on the drive.
I'm wondering if it's possible to move the page file to a different folder. I'm not saying that I want it to be on a different drive. I need them to both be on the same drive, but one of them needs to be in a different folder so that I can make the other one. Does anyone have a solution? The solution can be for Windows 10 or Windows 8.1. If the solution is for Windows 8.1, then I need to know how to create a page file in a specific folder in a drive. If the solution is for Windows 10, then I need to know how to move an existing page file to a different folder without breaking the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the folder where is stored the file `pagefile.sys`,
it's always stored in the root folder.

You can control the drive, so it's possible to create a small partition,
assign it a drive-letter, and move the file to it.

This is done in
*Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced >
Performance Settings > Advanced > Virtual memory Change*.