# Can I control how windows page file behaves?

Tags: linux, windows, swap, pagefile

As we all know Linux has swappiness option that we can change according to our needs to control how it behaves, so my question is, is there any command or anything like that what we can change to make page flie behave like how we want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I decrease the size of the page file?](https://superuser.com/questions/292989/how-do-i-decrease-the-size-of-the-page-file)

Comment: Also https://superuser.com/questions/1651735/moving-the-page-file-to-a-different-folder https://superuser.com/questions/237813/how-can-i-move-the-page-file-to-another-physical-disk-location etc.

Comment: keep in mind, the pagefile is used in windows for much more than just "swap". its a key component of the windows virtual memory management architecture, so its used even when you have plenty of free RAM. Its not just an overflow bucket. you can increase and decrease the size of the file, or even disable it entirely, but that will cause issues eventually.

Comment: @Destroy666 nope, I asked if there is something called swappiness.

Comment: @FrankThomas so does swap perform better than pagefile? I mean if you tell swappiness to 100 then linux also uses swap all the time. So is there any kind of swappiness control in windows.

Comment: Its not possible to generically answer on whether swap performs better. it varies by specific workload, and current system state. that said in linux swap feels kinda bolted on, just as overflow, but in windows VMM is a fully integrated part of how windows implements processes (a process is a memory structure; threads launched by them are what "executes"). the way RAM is offloaded/retrieved to/from paging is transparent to the application, and the OS controls it all. the goal is to make the overall system more stable, without regard for the specific apps running on it.

Comment: @jastyles that's not quite in your title and it's basically the same answer.